# Eclipse Package Explorer is always empty?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to keep my Java projects on a flash drive. Whenever I start up Eclipse, I choose the folder on my flash drive with all of my projects, but the package explorer is always empty.  I constantly have to make new duplicate projects and copy the text from the .java file.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you always start Eclipse on the same PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package explorer is reflective of the workspace that you have open. You generally want to start eclipse with the same workspace (for beginning users) and import your projects into that workspace. Don't search out and open eclipse in a project folder because that wont work.

My suggestion is to create your default workspace on your local hard drive, then when you want to create new projects, make sure you uncheck the `Use default location` and select the location of your flash drive. You can also import your existing projects on your flash drive to the default workspace.

Comment: I just didn't know about importing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Error Log view (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fau16690_.htm). You will see the reason why your projects cannot be opened. I would tip on having different drive name than you had last time.